# Refresh list in form panel

Tags: list, sencha-touch, refresh, formpanel

I have a list

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.view.RemoveList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List', //'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.removeList',
    config: {
        width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 300,
        height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 500,
        xtype: 'list',
        store: 'SiteEvaluations', //getRange(0, 9),
        itemTpl: [
            '<div><strong>Address: {address}</strong></div> '
        ],
        variableHeights: false
    }

});
```

that is rendered in a form panel:

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.view.Remove', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        fullscreen: true,
        config: {
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype : 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top'
                },
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    xtype: 'removeList' 

                }
            ]
        }
});
```

How do I refresh the list if it changes? For example, I have a method that onTap of an item in the list a MsgBox will give the option to delete that record from the store by given index. I tried a load() after doing the removal of the record, but this does not do the refresh (in a browser a refresh does it and in simulator, I have to exit and go back into the app).

Here is the MsgBox:

```
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title:'Are you sure?',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
        //animateTarget: 'mb4',
        //icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
        fn: function(buttonId) {
            //alert('You pressed the "' + buttonId + '" button.');

            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                evaluationsStore = Ext.getStore(evaluationStore); 
                index = evaluationStore.findExact('id', id); // get index of record

                console.log('index: ' + index);
                evaluationStore.removeAt(index); // remove record by index 
                evaluationStore.sync();
                alert('It is gone!');

                Ext.getStore(evaluationStore).load();

            }
            else {
                alert('Unscathed!');
            }   
        }   
    });
```

Grazie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the record is deleted from the database your list should update automatically. Store will generate 'update' event and list that has store will refresh it content. Are you saying it doesn't work this way for you?

Comment: Hi Sha, you are correct: The form panel has to be manually refreshed to get the update to the store. Is this a configuration option in the proxy, perhaps? I do have autoload: true.

Comment: autoLoad is different - it's for store to load automatically when application starts. Can you create a small fiddle so we can look at it and tell you what's wrong?

Comment: Oops! My syntax was wrong! This did the job:  Ext.StoreMgr.get('SiteEvaluations').load();
(I had an alias to the store in its config!).

Comment: Haste making waste, and all that rot!